# Java Microprofile change properties on already deployed app (Wildfly)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, config, microprofile

I have an ear artifact deployed on a wildfly server. On some beans I used the following configuration injection

```
@Inject
private Config config;
```

I want to change the properties specified on the "microprofile-config.properties" file on runtime. It is not necessary to change the file itself, I just want to change the properties. I think there might be a way using the console, but I cannot find if there is any.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [spec](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-config-2.0/microprofile-config-spec-2.0.pdf) or even at articles like [this](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/september/article3.php), you will see that, by default, Microprofile config reads configuration values from the following 3 places in this order - i.e. from wherever it finds it first:

1. `System.getProperties()`
2. `System.getenv()`
3. The configuration file

So, you can override values in the configuration file in 2 ways:

1. Defining `-D` command line arguments to the VM (e.g. `java -DXXX=yyy ...`)
2. Defining system environment variables (e.g. `export XXX=yyy` in bash or `set XXX=yyy` in Windows)

Note that there are some rules for defining environment variables and matching them to actual configurations, e.g. for a configuration `aaa.bbb.ccc` you may need to set an environment variable as `AAA_BBB_CCC`. Read ch. 5.3.1 in the specs, and experiment a little.

You can always extend the configuration sources with your own custom ones (to read configuration from JNDI, DB, Zookeeper, whatever).

Comment: Thanks, that cleared some things up. I was confused about the "aaa.bbb" style configuration values, since that's what we used. I might not be able to try this right now tho, since we are on a big crunch. It looks like that's the answer tho.

Comment: The question was about changing the values on runtime. Will the property change on runtime when I change them in the System properties?